# Setting datacontext for a datatemplate item

Tags: wpf, xaml

I am trying to set the `DataContext` for my datatemplate item `BuildStepsViewModel`. The below code works perfectly fine.

```
<StackPanel Margin="10" Name="controlDisplay" Visibility="{Binding Path=Visibility}">
    <ItemsControl HorizontalAlignment="Left" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Elements}" Width="Auto">
        <ItemsControl.Resources>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vms:BuildStepsViewModel}">
                <local:BuildStepsSelWindow>
                    <local:BuildStepsSelWindow.DataContext>
                        <vms:BuildStepsViewModel/>
                    </local:BuildStepsSelWindow.DataContext>
                </local:BuildStepsSelWindow>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.Resources>
    </ItemsControl>
 </StackPanel>
```

Now I am trying to reduce the verbose part in the datacontext set.

```
  <StackPanel Margin="10" Name="controlDisplay" Visibility="{Binding Path=Visibility}">
    <ItemsControl HorizontalAlignment="Left" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Elements}" Width="Auto">
        <ItemsControl.Resources>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vms:BuildStepsViewModel}">
                <local:BuildStepsSelWindow DataContext="{Binding Path=BuildStepsViewModel}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.Resources>
    </ItemsControl>
 </StackPanel>
```

But now the controls in the BuildStepsViewModel are not displaying correctly. Am I overlooking something?

Comment: Assuming that `Elements` is a collection of BuildStepsViewModel objects, you would not set any DataContext at all. The DataContext of the item container element (i.e. a ContentPresenter) and hence that of the elements in the DataTemplate is automatically set to the corresponding item from the ItemsSource collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first case the `DataContext` of is a new instance of vms:BuildStepsViewModel. This does not seem correct, as you want to bind the `DataTemplate` to an existing instance and not a new one.
In the second case the `DataContext` is bound to some `BuildStepsViewModel` property. The source is the old `DataContext` value. Unless the type `BuildStepsViewModel` has a property called `BuildStepsViewModel`, this binding will not work correctly. If I understand the case correctly, you can try omitting the data context, as it will be inherited and it will automatiacally become the correct `BuildStepsViewModel` instance:

```
 <ItemsControl.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vms:BuildStepsViewModel}">
            <local:BuildStepsSelWindow />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.Resources>
```

Comment: I tried omitting the `DataContext`, now the view is displaying correctly. But when I put a break point in view's constructor and inspected `this.DataContext`, it is `null`. Is this expected behavior?

Comment: Yes, DataContext is automatically propagated downwards through the elements tree, which happens a bit later. You can check this article https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.frameworkelement.datacontext?view=netframework-4.8

Answer (score 1):

These two snippets are not equivalent.

This

```
<local:BuildStepsSelWindow.DataContext>
    <vms:BuildStepsViewModel/>
</local:BuildStepsSelWindow.DataContext>
```

essentially means

```
this.DataContext = new BuildStepsViewModel();
```

So you instantiate a new viewmodel for each view instance.

But this:

```
<local:BuildStepsSelWindow DataContext="{Binding Path=BuildStepsViewModel}"/>
```

essentially means:

```
this.DataContext = this.DataContext.BuildStepsViewModel;
```

See? That makes no sense. You're trying to access a property named `BuildStepsViewModel` on the object stored as `DataContext`. But since there is no data context (yet), the binding returns null, and the data context is not set.

Consider reading thoroughly about [the data binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop-wpf/data/data-binding-overview). Also, read about [the XAML syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/xaml-syntax-in-detail).